# Extract single JSON Value with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, parsing, console, json.net

I have:

```
[
  {
    "account": "max",
    "address": "1DjA7XoVkB8bKRzcf5oW2MFtyN92u3ssEu",
    "category": "receive",
    "amount": 0.1,
    "confirmations": 290,
    "blockhash": "000000000000040f883801bd432ae638258dd852e124f8db349a9a6afc0bd4
df",
    "blockindex": 139,
    "blocktime": 1352407188,
    "txid": "cee56f0aa97f9200e7fcb220861098bd74419cf5427e81b02870cb9baf063560",
    "time": 1352407188,
    "timereceived": 1352550395
  }
]
```

What is the quickest way to get the value of txid? I have been trying combinations for hours.

EDIT: It's a JArray C# object, looks like this:

```
o = new JArray(o.First);
return o["txid"];
```

returns an error

Comment: Is it string or a javascript object?

Comment: What combinations? What didn't work? What exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: Parse it to object and get value like everyone else does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SoapHexBinary` in namespace `System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001`

```
var jArr = JArray.Parse(json);
var hex = SoapHexBinary.Parse((string)jArr[0]["txid"]);
byte[] buf  = hex.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code recieves as a string try this:

```
alert(eval('[{"account": "max","address": "1DjA7XoVkB8bKRzcf5oW2MFtyN92u3ssEu","category": "receive","amount": 0.1,"confirmations": 290,"blockhash": "000000000000040f883801bd432ae638258dd852e124f8db349a9a6afc0bd4
df","blockindex": 139,"blocktime": 1352407188,"txid": "cee56f0aa97f9200e7fcb220861098bd74419cf5427e81b02870cb9baf063560","time":1352407188,"timereceived": 1352550395}]')[0]["txid"]);
```

If the code is an javascript object try this one:

```
var obj = [
  {
    "account": "max",
    "address": "1DjA7XoVkB8bKRzcf5oW2MFtyN92u3ssEu",
    "category": "receive",
    "amount": 0.1,
    "confirmations": 290,
    "blockhash": "000000000000040f883801bd432ae638258dd852e124f8db349a9a6afc0bd4
df",
    "blockindex": 139,
    "blocktime": 1352407188,
    "txid": "cee56f0aa97f9200e7fcb220861098bd74419cf5427e81b02870cb9baf063560",
    "time": 1352407188,
    "timereceived": 1352550395
  }
];

alert(obj[0]["txid"]);
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers

Comment: This is JavaScript, not C#/Newtonsoft-JSON.

Comment: Sir with all do respect, it was your question issue made me mistake the answer. By the way, you said that it cause an error. Could you please give me some little information about the error?

Comment: something about the object not existing

Comment: I need the exact text to find that something. :)