# Newtonsoft get value from hierarchical JSON using single dynamic selector

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, json.net

I'm looking for a way to pass a single string selector to get a value from hierarchical JSON. This selector could be `id`, `location.name`, or even deeper, it has to be dynamic.

I have this JSON:

```
{
"generatedAt": "2022-01-01 02:03:25",
"myitems": [
{
    "id": "1795089",
    "location": {
        "name": "Myplace",
        "countryCode": "DE"\
    },
}
,
{
    "id": "1795070",
    "location": {
        "name": "Roseplace",
        "countryCode": "US"
    },
}

],
"count": 2
}
```

I want to select nested values by a SINGLE selector. E.g. `location.name`. I want this because I want to store the selector in a single field in my database.
I have tried this:

```
Dim obj As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
Dim jsonArray As JArray = DirectCast(obj("myitems"), JArray)
    
For Each item In jsonArray
    item("id").Value(Of String) 'works
    item("location")("name").Value(Of String) 'works    
    item("location.name").Value(Of String) 'does NOT work
Next
```

I considered storing the selector in my database like `location.name` and then when executing the selector in my code, first splitting that selector by `.`, and then build it like `item(selectorpart(0))(selectorpart(1)).Value(Of String)`
However, I have a lot of fields that I need to select and it would be a lot of extra code if I need to split each selector first. Also because many times my JSON is not as nested as above and I wouldn't need to split the selector at all.

How could I do this?

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795045/accessing-all-items-in-the-jtoken), but the described requirement seems different than mine.
I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324834/extract-single-json-value-with-newtonsoft) but it doesn't apply to nested structures.
Also, I'm reading JSON feeds from different providers so I can't simply create a single class as was suggested in some other threads, and I don't want to have to map each feed
structure to a class.

Comment: If `item("location")("name").Value(Of String)` works, then what is your problem?  What do you mean by *single dynamic selector*?  Do you mean a [JSONPath query string](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm)?

Comment: If a [JSONPath query](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) is what you want, this looks to be a duplicate of [Searching for a specific JToken by name in a JObject hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29782523/3744182) and/or [What is the JSON.NET equivalent of XML's XPath, SelectNodes, SelectSingleNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19645501/3744182).  Your query would be `obj.SelectTokens("myitems[*].location.name")` from the root, or `item.SelectToken("location.name")` while looping through the array.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: I was looking for the right terminology indeed. But thanks, `item.SelectToken("location.name")` is exactly what I was looking for!